# Text conditionals in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I want to write a formula where I can add values to a cell whether another cell states approves the "transaction".

It will be easier to explain with an example. Consider a spreadsheet containing the costs of a flat share.

```
Purchase    Adam Joe Peter To
 x           $5  $5   $0   Peter
 y           $0  $7   $7   Adam
```

Given the table above, I would like to create another table showing how much money do people owe each other:

```
      Owe to
      Adam  Joe  Peter
Adam   $0    $0   $5
Joe    $7    $0   $5
Peter  $7    $0   $0
```

I am not sure how to create the second table. Any ideas how? I was thinking of something along the lines of a loop, and if statements.

Comment: Can you share a doc with us?

Answer (score 1):

If you're thinking about "loop and if statements", you should look into [Google Apps Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_spreadsheet).

Other than that, it seems you're looking for the `TRANSPOSE` function, in conjunction with the `FILTER` function. Take a look at the [Google Spreadsheets Function List](https://support.google.com/docs/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=25273&page=table.cs).

If you can tell me the purpose of the `Purchase` column in your example, I might be able to set up a working example.

Comment: the Purchase column is simply a description of a purchase in the flat - its not directly relevant to the question. For example, Peter buys x, and it costs him $15 - so Adam and Joe each owe him $5. This is reflected in the Owe To table (the one I am trying to build).